# What is a valid public key in Monero?

Tags: viewkey, spend-key

I know that it's important to run sc_reduce() first to filter some invalid scalar when I need a private key.

How about public keys in Monero? How can I ensure its format is right?

Please help to answer it, many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sc_reduce` just takes a 256 bit number and reduces it mod  to yield a scalar of the correct curve order. Nothing special. Any number between 0 and  is a valid scalar.

For a *point* (which is what a public key is) however, the bytes need to first decode to a point and this can vary based on what format has been used to store the point. Assuming it's a compressed 32 byte point, this will consist of the `y` coordinate (a scalar) combined with a 1 bit sign (used during recovery). Thus after taking the binary of the `y` coordinate, one must *recover* the `x` coordinate. This is a little more involved but covered perfectly well in [[ref](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032#section-5.1.3)]. Having recovered `x` one can then check the resulting  `x,y` point is actually on the curve with a check such as: `(-x*x + y*y - 1 - d*x*x*y*y) % q == 0`. In practice, you will be using a tried-and-tested library to do any decoding / point operations.